# Debian vm on GCP, process is stopping by itself, how to diagnose?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have a Debian vm on GCP. I have a python script that runs properly on my development machine (Arch).  When I run it on the GCP vm it runs for 20 mins or so then stops.  When I `ps aux` it shows the running process, then when I come back a half hour later the process is gone.

In the python script I have logging set up, but there is nothing in the log file, even though all functions are in a try/except with logging exceptions as logging.debug(). What do I need to learn to diagnose this issue? How can I figure out what specifically is causing the process to stop?

Comment: How are you running the script? As a system process or from a terminal window session?

Comment: From a terminal. I'm running `python module.py`.

Comment: When the terminal session ends or times out, your Python program will also end. Either create a system process or use a program such as `screen`.

Comment: When does the terminal session end, is it when I close the terminal? And how do you create a system process?

Comment: I cannot answer without detail, such as the Linux version, which your program does, etc. Search for documents link this one: https://linuxhandbook.com/create-systemd-services/

Comment: OK well your answer has already helped a lot, I'm learning screen right now.  Thanks